# How to remove notelist item for Android?

Tags: android

I learn how to add a list item for note list, but I can't find any tutorial on how to remove the list item, can anyone teach me ? How can I remove the item from the list?

this is my note_add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:text="New To Do Item">
        </EditText>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSimple"
        android:text="Add Note"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bDeleteNote"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bDeleteNote"
        android:layout_marginRight="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="66dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/bDeleteNote"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSimple"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bDeleteNote">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my note.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Note extends HomePage {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes_add);

        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        final ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,noteList);
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);
        Button btnSimple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSimple);
        btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                noteList.add(0,myEditText.getText().toString());
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                myEditText.setText("");
            }
        });


    }
}
```

how can I remove item in the list?

Comment: This literally took me 2 seconds to google. [android arraylist documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //this remove the first view.You can remove view by index.
                noteList.remove(0);
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                myEditText.setText("");
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks ya :) its really clear for beginner , thanks a lot